# Temporarily adding a self-signed certificate to a local truststore

Tags: java, ssl, x509certificate, keystore

I run a java application that uses httpsconnections. On the server there is a self-signed certificate. on my local machine I have a copy of this certificate, on path `C:\Whatever\mycertificate.cer`. i want to make it so my local machine accepts the self-signed certificate as trusted for https connection (in addition to normal signed certificates) ONLY for my application and ONLY while the application is running.

The input parameter for my program is the path to the certificate. I use the following code to convert it to a java object `X509Certificate`:

```
CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(pathToTheCertificateFile);
        X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
```

Next I create a new empty `Keystore` (truststore) and add the certificate object to it:

```
KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null);
        trustStore.setCertificateEntry("extra", certificate);
```

Lastly, I create a `TrustManager` using a `TrustManagerFactory`:

```
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(trustStore);
```

Lastly, I use these array of trustmanagers to init the SSLContext

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

There are 3 problems with this:

1. It doesn't work - so what step did I do wrong?
2. This set-up will allow ONLY the given certificate, not the union of the given
   certificate + the normal cacerts. How can I add the additional
   certificates?
3. I'm not sure this only works TEMPORARILY (until application stops) and LOCALLY (only for my application) - does
   anybody know if this is the case? and if ont, what can I change to
   achieve this?

Comment: "*It doesn't work*": how does it fail? Are you sure your client connections use `HttpsURLConnection`? (You should be able to see that from the stack trace.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a decent discussion of this problem here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/40207/why-ie-windows-forces-you-to-install-self-signed-certificates-as-root-ca-to-make.  In a nutshell, this is intentionally hard to do.  Is there a reason you can't just add exceptions to your browser(s)?

Comment: As a developer (not end-user) I **know** what am I  doing. So it's really briliant idea to make doing this difficult *by design* in some programming language.